# How to set up an array for audio files in HTML on Squarespace?

Tags: html, squarespace

So I am trying to integrate some custom code onto Squarespace in order to play audio when you click an image. I am a complete beginner to web dev but I found some HTML code which did the job for one image. So when I click on the image it plays audio. However, this only works for one image and for one audio file. I am assuming that if I want to click on different images, each playing their own audio file, I would have to set up an array for both the image files and audio files. I am not sure if this is the correct solution but if it is, how would I set up an array in HTML? Thanks! Attached is an image of my code.

[image: image here]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Arrays are data objects in programming languages like JavaScript etc., there is no way to set up an array in HTML other than manually copy/pasting the elements with their desired image/audio files or perhaps with a templating engine.  What precisely is the problem you are trying to solve?  Are you trying to write code that will play the audio file related to an image, or are you trying to generate that HTML structure programatically?

Comment: Basically I am trying to get an image to play audio on click. I was successful when it was only one image but I would like to have many images that play their own audio file. It would be one audio file per image. In my code above, the script is set up to play the function play( ) onclick which plays the "audio" variable. But this structure only allows for one audio file. If I set up an another image to play the function play( ) onclick, it would only play the first audio file. As I said, I would like multiple images with the functionality to play their own corresponding audio file.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is give the images a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) containing the URL/file name for the audio you want that image to play, and write a function that switches out the source on a single audio element when the image is clicked.  Something like:

```
<img class="audio-img" data-audio="path/to/myfile1.mp3"/>
<img class="audio-img" data-audio="path/to/myfile2.mp3"/>
<img class="audio-img" data-audio="path/to/myfile3.mp3"/>
<audio id="audio" src=""/>
```

And then write a function to get that audio and play it and attach it to the images:

```
function playAudio(event) {
  const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  const url = event.target.getAttribute('data-audio'); 
  audio.src = url;
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}

const images = document.getElementsByClassName('audio-img');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].addEventListener("click", playAudio);
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/LoaZyM) with some random sound files I had.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out when I get home, I appreciate it!